# Select specific portion of text using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


my_url = 'https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/S63.SI/history?p=S63.SI'


uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

item = container.findAll("td", {"class":"D(ib) Fz(18px)"})
print(item.text)
```

**Output**

`Singapore Technologies Engineering Ltd (S63.SI)`

I only need to get `S63.SI` is their anyway to filter my output to so it does not give the rest of the output seen above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it without using RegEX:

```
text = "Singapore Technologies Engineering Ltd (S63.SI)"

ib = text[text.find("(")+1:text.find(")")]

print(ib)
```

Output:

```
S63.SI
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to capture the value within the paranthesis

```py
import re
text = "Singapore Technologies Engineering Ltd(S63.SI)"
result = re.findall(r'\(([\w\d\.]+)\)', text)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['S63.SI']
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use regular expression something like r'.*((.*))$' will match the string and put the thing between parenthesis into group1. see https://regex101.com/ for more details

```
import re

regex = r".*\((.*)\)$"

test_str = "Singapore Technologies Engineering Ltd (S63.SI)"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of an alternative to `regex`:

```
string="Singapore Technologies Engineering Ltd (S63.SI)"
output=string.split()[-1].strip('(').strip(')')
```

**Comments:**

- `string.split()` will split your text into separate words
- for the last word (`string.split()[-1]`), strip parentheses
  characters

Comment: I like using the split method, the downside is it fails if the string was missing a bracket or two.

Comment: `.split()` splits on whitespace, while `strip` removes brackets if they exist, else do nothing. Maybe you can share the failing scenario?

Comment: I completely misread your code. Apologies. That's a clever way of doing it.